# self.close() not working with chrome and firefox

Tags: javascript

```
My Code:-

<BODY onload="redireccionar();">

 <SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
  function redireccionar() {
    setTimeout("self.close()", 500);

  }
  </SCRIPT>
```

Above is my code regarding facing issues on chrome and firefox while it works fine with IE. I have tried almost all functions available here but still facing the same.
please suggest any solution. Thanks in advance.

Comment: was the window opened as a pop up?

Comment: yes..pop up is coming on IE only but not on other browser's

Comment: so is your problem with opening the popup or closing it?

Comment: i want that pop up to close the window or to stay in that window with both 'YES' or 'NO' option

Comment: Use `window.close` instead of self.close

Comment: already used that but no change...

Answer (score 0):

I searched everywhere and found out that you have to trick the browser into thinking it was opened w/JavaScript.  This worked for me in Firefox and IE:

```
<a href="javascript:window.open('','_parent','');window.close();">Close this window</a>
```